# altering label properties inside of a function

Tags: vb.net

I was just wondering if this was possible. I'm trying to validate a form to be filled out by the users, and when the required section isn't filled, I increment an

ErrorCount += 1

variable to show that error(s) have occurred inside the program, I then also set an

ErrorArray()

to whatever the corresponding field number is, now I have 0-12 (13 fields). What I have also done is titled the labels that are associated with all of these fields to correspond with the ErrorArray() value that might be set, such as.

PatLabel0
PatLabel1 etc.

What I am trying to do is loop through the array contents, depending on which ErrorArray() values have been set, to go and set the corresponding fontcolor property of that label to red, to show that these now need to be filled out. This is what I have, but Visual Studio doesn't allow me to use the iteration through the loop as a reference to changing properties. Can anyone point me in the right direction to trying to figure this out, or at least tell me what else I could do. Just seems doing 20 if....then....else.... statements with 2 - 3 lines in each of them is redundant when 1 function line could do the same job. This is what I have.

```
for i = 0 to UBound(ErrorArray(12))

if(ErrorArray(i) = "*")then

    PatLabel(i).forecolor = color.red

else

    PatLabel(i).forecolor = color.black

end if

next
```

that is basically all im looking for initially, but I can't do it.
Thanks for any help in advance, and I know I have another similar post asking the question, just thought it may have been titled and explained poorly.
-NickG

Comment: I know i'm writing in VB.Net, but to be honest i'm not sure if this is even the proper syntax for VB.Net, i've coded in 99% PHP for the last 18 months and am not even sure where to begin to cross over, if you have any tutorial advice for me i'd be happy to take it

Comment: But why label the question as C# if you're not *using* C#?

Comment: i'm sorry, it says that i labeled it as vb.net on my page here, it was a mistake obviously

Comment: No, you tagged it as C#. robyaw edited the tags to change it to VB...

Answer (score 0):

No idea what your code means but here is some C# to do the trick...

```
for(int i = 0; i < ErrorArray.Length; i++)
{
   if(ErrorArray[i] == "*")
   {
      PatLabel(i).ForeColor = Color.Red;
   }
   else
   {
      PatLabel(i).ForeColor = Color.Black;
   }
}
```

this assumes that ErrorArray is a string[] or something of the kind (list etc.) and that PatLabel is a function that takes the index position for the control and return the Control to be changed.

If PatLabel is an array of control you would alter the ForeColor property like this...

```
PatLabel[i].ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

An example function that could set the property of a control given a number ID...

```
void SetControlColor(int i, Color color)
{
    Label label = Panel1.Controls["PatLabel" + i] AS Label;
    if(label != null)
    {
       label.ForeColor = color;
    }
}
```

you can then call the function from the above for loop like...

```
for(int i = 0; i < ErrorArray.Length; i++)
{
   if(ErrorArray[i] == "*")
   {
      SetControlColor(i, Color.Red);
   }
   else
   {
      SetControlColor(i, Color.Black);
   }
}
```

**NOTE**: This question was tagged as C# when I wrote the initial code examples

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm really new with using VB, I always program in PHP and it's not quite the same, that's for sure.  PatLabel is just what I named all the labels in the form, to correspond with whatever point in the ErrorArray[] array is set in case of an error.  Basically something like 

PatLabel0
PatLabel1
PatLabel2 etc..  are the names of the labels on the form, if the user submits the form without filling out the corresponding textbox to these labels than I want to change the font property to red, that's really it.

Comment: If I was to create a function called PatLabel() could I just pass in the value of i, and depending on the value of i, set the ForeColor Property to the corresponding Label?

Comment: @NickG, I have updated my answer to include a sample function. Unfortunately (for you) I don't do VB.Net so my code is in C# - you will have to try to convert it if you want to use any of it (there are online converters around if you do a Google search)

Comment: thank you for your sample, I will work on the conversion and let you know how I make out with it, sorry about the wrong tagging of the question initially, and thank you for tagging it correctly and helping me out with this issue.